# WordPress not showing pagination links

Tags: functions, pagination, next-post-link, previous-post-link

In my WordPress Index.html I am pulling out the 3 latest posts by using

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3') ?>

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   //rest of the post related data

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();  ?>
<?php do_action('show_navigation');
```

after that I want to fetch the next 3 or previous 3 posts and for this I am trying

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_content_navigation' ) ) {
    function theme_content_navigation( ) {
        global $wp_query;

        if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
            <nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( '<' ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( '>' ); ?></div>
            </nav>
        <?php 
        }
    }
}



add_action('show_navigation', 'theme_content_navigation');
```

this code in functions.php.

Right now I have 4 posts and three of them are displaying in my index.php but I am unable to see the navigation links to fetch next posts and replace the existing ones in index.php. Kindly suggest me how to fetch next or previous posts.

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem by removing

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3') ?>
```

and tried limiting posts from Settings->Reading. Thanks